# Should I write "encode X into format Y" or "encode X in format Y"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, technical

In technical writing involving such things as file formats, should one write "encode such-and-such *into* format Y" or write "encode such-and-such *in* format Y"?  In other words, which preposition (*into* or *in*) is more correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fear you shall find no absolute answer, for this is more a matter of common collocations than it is a matter of “correctness”. Both are in common use, and  probably interchangeably:

- Your binary string needs to be encoded in ASCII hex before transmission.
- Oh crap, this file has been encoded in UTF-16, and with Windows line terminators, too!
- You should first encode into UTF-8 before sending out over the net.

If you are using the verb *encode* actively, as I did in my final example, it **might** be better with *into*. But I would hesitate to say that using *in* where I have used *into* and using *into* where I have used *in* would be “incorrect”. I probably wouldn’t even notice.